# Custom metadata with unknown parameter length?

Tags: dart

I'm wondering if it's possible to create a custom annotation that can have a variable number of parameters.  Perhaps a pseudo-example would be best.  Here's where I'm starting:

```dart
class TestMetadata {
  final int prop;
  final String prop2;

  const TestMetadata({int prop, String prop2}) : this.prop = prop, this.prop2 = prop2;
}

const TestMetadata testMetadata = const TestMetadata();
```

Currently, this will let you annotate anything like so:

```dart
@testMetadata
void myFunction() {

}

@TestMetadata(prop:1, prop2:"Hello")
void myOtherFunction() {

}
```

I'd like to be able to feed in more parameters without having to explicitly define them.  I've tried to add a Map (It's all I could think of) to the TestMetadata class, like so:

```dart
class TestMetadata {
  final int prop;
  final String prop2;
  final Map theRest;

  const TestMetadata({int prop, String prop2, Map theRest}) : this.prop = prop, this.prop2 = prop2, this.theRest = theRest;
}
```

but when trying to access the Map from an annotation like so:

```dart
@TestMetadata(prop:1, prop2:"Hello", theRest:{param:"World"})
void myOtherFunction() {

}
```

I get an error that says:

"Arguments of a constant creation must be constant expressions."  Fair enough, that makes sense.  Does anyone else have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `Map` for your metadata, but you need to pass the `Map` in the following way:

```dart
@TestMetadata(prop:1, prop2:"Hello", theRest:const{"param":"World"})
```

The `Map` needs to be contant expression (hence the `const`) and you need to use a `String` for the `Map` key.